# Error in read.fasta

Tags: r

While using seqinr package to read fasta file and predict the length of fasta sequence for code,following the error being shown--

> ```
>    library("seqinr")
>    ncrna <- read.fasta(file = "ncrna_noncode_v3.fasta")
>    length(ncra)
>    Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 85 did not have 14 elements
> ```

Please suggest a possible solution for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Biostrings` package from Bioconductor.

```
library(Biostrings)
ncrna <- readDNAStringSet("ncrna_noncode_v3.fasta")
# use `width` to see the length of each sequence
str(width(ncrna))
```

BTW, please show part of your fasta file.